# delay call on function execution within each loop

Tags: jquery

I want to execute a function for each item within an array. However I don't want the function to be executed all at the same time. I would like for it to say execute the function for the first item, then wait 2 seconds before it executes the function for the second element. How could i do this I'm not too sure. Thanks!

```
$.each(sliderArray, function(index, value) {
       console.log("array value is "+this);
       openQv(this);
   });
```

Comment: setTimeout() and recursion

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setTimeout()` and most importantly don't forget to create a scope per iteration,

```
$.each(sliderArray, function(index, value) {
    var $this = this;
    (function(i){ 
       setTimeout(function(){ openQv($this) }, i*2000) 
    })(index);
});
```

Comment: Wow you was quick, nice answer :)

Comment: I get SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Comment: @user1937021 A closing parenthesis was missed. corrected it.

Comment: say i is undefined now

Comment: @user1937021 `(index)` pass index instead of `i`

Answer (score 0):

Would `setTimeout()` suffice?

```
$.each(sliderArray, function(index, value) {
       var $this = index;
        setTimeout(function()
        {
          console.log("array value is " + $this);
          openQv($this);
        },2000); 
   });
```

Comment: Could you post your openQv function?

Answer (score 0):

If you desire the delays to operate in series you could try something like this:

```
function open(items, delayBetweenItems) {
    function handleItem(itemIndex) {
        // open the item in question
        openQv(items[ itemIndex ]);

        var nextItemIndex = itemIndex + 1;

        // ensure it exists
        if (!items[ nextItemIndex ]) {
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            handleItem(nextItemIndex);
        }, delayBetweenItems);
    }

    handleItem(0);
}

open(sliderArray, 200);
```

This would wait 200 milliseconds between each item getting processed, such that you'd get progressive effect